# Deploying resources using bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli, azure-bicep

Trying to deploy resources on Azure for this we are using bicep from microsoft.

For the execution of the code I am  using visual studio code insider.

**Note** This is an example which I am posting here.

*Code is as follows*

```
    resource stg 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' = {
  name: 'uniquestorage001' // must be globally unique
  location: 'eastus'
  kind: 'Storage'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
}
```

at the terminal we use the following command to build it

bicep build main.bicep

I get the below error message

```
bicep: The term 'bicep' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again
```

I have installed the bicep extension.

I am really not sure what can be done further kindly help
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this documentation to install bicep:
[Install Bicep tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/install)

You need to install [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/install#azure-cli) then you will be able to install bicep:

```
az bicep install
```

To build you bicep file you can then use:

```
az bicep build --file main.bicep
```

Also you don't need to build your bicep file before deploying it, AZ CLI allow you to deploy directly your bicep file

```
az deployment group create --resource-group "my resource group name" --template-file ".\main.bicep"
```

Comment: thanks for the response.

I was able to install bicep tools 

`Bicep CLI version 0.4.613 (d826ce8411)`

Note: I am using cloud shell to run bicep. so far it looks it is working thanks so much for the guidance